# A list of items does not show more and less items when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Somehow my list of items does not show more or show less when clicking a button.

First you should see 3 items and a button with "+". Then when you click "+" the other items should show and then when clicking "-" the items limit back to 3 items again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var x = $("#list .content"),
      y = "<span class='present'>+</span>";
  x.find("a").length > 3 && (x.toggleClass("div_hide"), x.append(y)),
  $(".present").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("div_hide"), "-" == $(this).text() 
      ? $(this).html("+") 
      : $(this).html("-")
```

```
#list .div_hide a:nth-child(n+3) {
  display: none !important;
}
span.present {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```
<h1>List</h1>
  <div id="list">
    <a class="content" href="#">one</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">two</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">three</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">four</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">five</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">six</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you have any errors? Did you check your console log?

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle, or even better - codesandbox?

Comment: give full js, my fiddle screaming for unclosed functions

Comment: I suspect that x.find("a").length will always be 0 because the .content class is the <a> tag. The "find" looks for an <a> inside .content

Comment: Replace `.find("a")` with `.filter("a")`. As Jonas points out, you're searching for descendant `<a>` elements of `.content` elements, of which there are none. `.filter()` will look for `.content` elements that are *also* `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an dynamic example based on your code.

```
  var $listElements = $("#list a");

      $listElements.hide();
      $listElements.filter(':lt(2)').show();
            $('#list').append('<a><span>+</span><span class="less">-</span></ai>');

$("#list").find('a:last').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(':gt(1)').toggle('slow');
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});
```

You can have as many content elements as you like

```
<h1>List</h1>
  <div id="list">
    <a class="content" href="#">one</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">two</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">three</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">four</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">five</a>
    <a class="content" href="#">six</a>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahentea/jwLhd7o2/

Answer (score 0):

look this ans i have do this with jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var x = $("#list .content"),
            y = "<span class='present'>+</span>";
           $("#list .content:last-child").after(y);
           
             $(".content").each(function(index){
                 if(index>=3){
                  $(this).addClass('toBeshow dNone');
                 }
             });
            $(document).on('click', '.present', function(){
              $(".toBeshow").toggleClass('dNone');
            });
                });
```

```css
span.present {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    background: yellow;
}
.dNone{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>List</h1>
    <div id="list">
      <a class="content" href="#">one</a>
      <a class="content" href="#">two</a>
      <a class="content" href="#">three</a>
      <a class="content" href="#">four</a>
      <a class="content" href="#">five</a>
      <a class="content" href="#">six</a>
    </div>
```